# Https website shows login prompt, http shows normal website

Tags: windows, iis, iis-10

I have a new windows server that I set up IIS on. I used certify the web to install an SSL certificate on my server. The Https website shows a login prompt while non https loads the page normally. I have verified that only anonymous authentication is selected under authentication.

- Here are the selected authentication modes
  [image: Here are the selected authentication modes]
- The bindings of the website
  [image: The bindings of the website]

Comment: The binding shouldn't make any difference on the authentication. What exactly does the login prompt look like. Any clues on there?

Comment: It shows a prompt for username and password

Comment: You already said that, and it is not what was asked! Again, what exactly does the login prompt look like? You can certainly take another screenshot.

Comment: Its a similar image to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l8z7.jpg.
I shut down the server and started a new one in a different region and didn't get the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone, I struggled with this for a while with an internal website. I needed to add the https url to the 'Local Intranet' zones. Voila problem solved!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ5qL.png)